# PDF generado por FPDF genera márgenes blancos al imprimir pero al generarlo con mi programa no se muestran

Tags: php, fpdf

Tengo un problema y es que que cuando genero el pdf mediante FPDF en mi programa me lo muestra correctamente en la previsualización pero al imprimirlo genera unos márgenes en los filos como de 5mm que no se porque se generan. Tengo todo configurado para que el tamaño sea A4, he probado al imprimir que se ajuste al tamaño del papel, he probado a cambiar los márgenes, etc. pero siguen apareciendo. Desconozco porque sucede, si es algo que genera por defecto FPDF o como se puede solucionar. Si a alguien le ha sucedido lo mismo y ha sabido arreglarlo le agradecería que me dijera que hay que hacer.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]  deberias : Editar la pregunta, añadir el codigo  y un breve resumen sobre lo que esta mal o no entiendes.    Tambien es recomendable leer este     apartado [ask]

Comment: ¿Has probado en una impresora diferente que sí que imprima toda la superficie? No todas las impresoras consiguen imprimir hasta el mismísimo borde del papel :)